# What is the best way to track non event releated analytics data

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have installed Google analytics for Android into my app which is good to track install referrers and event data such as button clicks.

However I am also wanting gather information such as:

1. If the user has installed my apps widget or not
2. Things like sizes of user entries (eg, the user has 25 contacts if it was a phonebook
   app).
3. Which options the user has turned on or off
4. etc etc

I cant find a suitable way to collect this data in Google analytics.

Can someone please advise me if its suitable to use Google Analytics for this kind of non-event data and if so, how?

If Google Analytics is not suitable can someone suggest a service I can use or would it be best for me to build my own purpose built custom solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define [Custom Dimensions in your Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/customdimsmets)

then when the next screenview or event is triggered those dimensions will be associated with it. Afterwards you will be able to filter / create advanced segments in Google Analytics Reports.

You can set also the scope of your dimension. So you can for example set single hit scope or session scope or even a user scope.

To be more specific to your question you could for example create a user-scope var for `hasWidgetInstalled` like this:

```
//assuming you have created inside Google Analytics Account Admin a custom dimension with the id 1
//and the name "hasWidgetInstalled"
EasyTracker.getTracker()setCustomDimension(1, "true");
```

**Update:** 
please note that you cannot set unique user identifiers (like for example emails etc.) as custom dimensions, because it is against [Google Analytics Policy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy), see:

> You will not upload any data that allows Google to personally identify an individual (such as certain names, social security numbers, email addresses, or any similar data), or data that permanently identifies a particular device (such as a mobile phone’s unique device identifier if such an identifier cannot be reset), even in hashed form.

Comment: Thanks just reading it now, im using V3 of GA so its changed a bit from your example and your link - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/customdimsmets

Comment: yeah should be pretty similar in V3

Comment: When you say user scope. Can I associate a Unique User Identifier with the dimension somehow? that way I can know exactly which of my users have the widget installed? Thanks again

Comment: Hmm I also noticed there is a limit on Custom Dimensions of 20..

Comment: Yes there is a limit of 20 custom dimensions, but that should be enough, shouldn't it? Please also see my update of the answer

Comment: I feel that GA is a **ok** solution for non event data, however it could be improved. Thanks for the help